# Using Object.keys(), map(), ...Array(), reduce() and concat() in a single const

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm learning React.js on Udemy. We wrote a long stateless component which used `Object.keys()`, `map()`, `...Array`, `reduce()` and `concat()` in a single const.

I know every method we used in this stateless component. But when I used them all in a single component I lost a track.

Like why did we put `[]` on  `reduce()` method as second parameter or what does `(_, i)` is for on `map()`method?

Can you explain this code step by step?

```
const burger = (props) => {

     let transformedIngredients = Object.keys( props.ingredients )
      .map( igKey => {

         return [...Array( props.ingredients[igKey] )].map( (_, i) => {
            return <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />;
         });
      }) 
     .reduce((arr, el) => {
          return arr.concat(el);
     }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Object.keys( props.ingredients )
```

retrieves an array of ingredients names.

```
 .map( igKey => {
```

maps that array to a new array, were each element contains

```
 [...Array( props.ingredients[igKey] )]
```

an array that has as many entries as the value related to the ingredient in the passed object.

```
 .map( (_, i) => {
```

then maps that inner array, ignores the value (which is `undefined` for an empty array anyways) and only takes the index and maps it to

```
      <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />;
```

Now we do have a 2D array of BurgerIngredients, and

```
 .reduce((arr, el) => {
      return arr.concat(el);
 }, []);
```

flattens that to an array of BurgerIngredients. *Reducing* means that we start with the initial value (`[]`) and `.concat` every value (inner array) of the original array to it.

---

I'd write that as:

```
 const Burger = ({ ingredients }) => {
   const list = [];

   for(const [ingredient, amount] of Object.entries(ingredients)) {
     for(let count = 0; count < amount; count++) {
        list.push(<BurgerIngredient key={ingredient + count} type={ingredient} />);
     }
  }

  return <div className="burger">
    Ingredients:
    {list}
  </div>;
};
```

Comment: @giorgim cause `props.ingredients[igKey]` is probably a number e.g. 3, then `Array(3)` returns an empty array of length 3, and `[...Array(3)]` returns an array with three empty slots. `3.map` won't work.

Comment: But when you write like you would, how do you access ingredients without props? Also thanks for explanatory answer. I would be appreciate if you vote up my question because I think this a good example of using "hard to learn methods" in a single example.

Comment: I *destructure* it. `{ ingredients }` takes out the ingredients property of the passed object.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for a different approach.